# INNER JOIN 3 tables and choose based on dates

Tags: postgresql

I am pretty new to Postgresql so please bare with me. I am trying to inner join three tables that have the structure below. The trips table has the trip_id which the tables trip_pickup and trip_dropoff have multiple entries of. Each trip has multiple pickup and dropoffs but one driver and one trailer/truck. What I am trying to display is the trip_id and the first pickup and last dropoff. The query I have now displays all the combinations of the pickup and dropoffs. Is there a technique that I don't know of that could help me in this? I would greatly appreciate it if you could help.

**trips**

| trip_id | truck_id | diver_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 15 |

**trip_pickup**

| p_date | order_number | p_city | p_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/05/2022 | 1 | Houston | TX |
| 01/08/2022 | 2 | Surprise | AZ |
| 01/09/2022 | 3 | Phoenix | AZ |

**trip_dropoff**

| d_date | order_number | d_city | d_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/15/2022 | 1 | NOGALES | AZ |
| 01/17/2022 | 2 | Glendale | MI |
| 01/22/2022 | 3 | Las Vegas | NV |

```
SELECT trips.trip_id, trip_pickup.p_date, trip_pickup.p_city, trip_pickup.p_state, 
trip_dropoff.d_date, trip_dropoff.d_city, trip_dropoff.d_state, trip_dropoff.d_date, 
trips.truck_id, drivers.first_name, drivers.last_name

FROM trips INNER JOIN trucks ON trucks.truck_id = trips.truck_id

INNER JOIN drivers ON drivers.driver_id = trips.driver_id

INNER JOIN trailers ON trailers.trailer_id = trips.trailer_id

INNER JOIN trip_pickup ON trip_pickup.trip_id = trips.trip_id

INNER JOIN trip_dropoff ON trip_dropoff.trip_id = trips.trip_id

ORDER BY trip_pickup.p_date DESC LIMIT 20;
```

**Desired Example Output:**

| trip_id | truck_id | driver_id | p_date | p_city | p_state | d_date | d_city | d_state |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 56 | 15 | 01/05/2022 | Houston | TX | 01/22/2022 | Las Vegas | NV |

Comment: Please define what a "first pickup" and "last dropoff" are, in terms of the columns in your table(s).  Data in SQL tables are not intrinsically ordered. Example output would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Hello, the "first pickup" is the record with the earliest date and the "last dropoff" is the record with the latest date or furthest date from the first pickup. I have included an example output above for more clarity. Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and that would work perfectly but sometimes there are trips that have different drop off with the same date. In that case I restructured my database to include the order which the dropoff and and pickups should be in. I hope this helps.

Comment: I have updated the query to use order_number.

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked perfectly, much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get everything in one row, I used filtered aggregates on top of a union of the `trip_pickup` and `trip_dropoff` tables with a direction indicator.

I assumed that there is supposed to be a `trip_id` column in `trip_pickup` and `trip_dropoff` that is not in the example tables (but appears in your working query).

If the tables are very large, and `trip_pickup` and `trip_dropoff` have indexes over `trip_id,{p,d}_date`, then replacing the CTE self-join with the original tables might improve performance. The benefit increases if you ever want to query a subset of `trip_id`s.

No version of PostgreSQL was provided, so I assume you are running a supported version, which will have the necessary features for this query.

```
WITH cte AS (
SELECT 'p' AS direction, trip_id, p_date AS leg_date, p_city AS city, p_state AS state, order_number
  FROM trip_pickup
UNION ALL
SELECT 'd', trip_id, d_date, d_city, d_state, order_number
  FROM trip_dropoff
)

SELECT trips.trip_id,
    trips.truck_id,
    trips.driver_id,
    cte_1.leg_date AS p_date,
    cte_1.city AS p_city,
    cte_1.state AS p_state,
    cte_2.leg_date AS d_date,
    cte_2.city AS d_city,
    cte_2.state AS d_state
 FROM (
    SELECT cte.trip_id,
    min(order_number) FILTER (WHERE direction='p') AS first_pickup_seq,
    max(order_number) FILTER (WHERE direction='d') AS last_dropoff_seq
    FROM cte
    GROUP BY cte.trip_id) t
JOIN trips USING (trip_id)
JOIN cte cte_1 ON (cte_1.direction='p' AND t.trip_id=cte_1.trip_id AND t.first_pickup_seq=cte_1.order_number)
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte cte_2 ON (cte_2.direction='d' AND t.trip_id=cte_2.trip_id AND t.last_dropoff_seq=cte_2.order_number)
ORDER BY p_date DESC LIMIT 20
```

**UPDATE**

Altered query to use trip order_number instead of date. This should address tie-breaking any same-day pickups or dropoffs. For the record, the same could have been accomplished by recording pickup and dropoff time as timestamps.